# get value in windows form into another class?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

Code On Windows form is

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            CandleCollection collection = GetCandleCollection();
            int Dim = int.Parse(txt_agent.Text);
            int NumParticles = int.Parse(txt_part.Text);

            SOSManager p = new SOSManager(collection);

          //this part 
            p.Dim = Dim;
            p.NumParticles = NumParticles;

            m_part = new ParticleSwarm(fit,p.Dim, p.NumParticles);



    }
```

So,I want to add value that i put on textbox to this class.

```
public class SOSManager
{        
    private ParticleSwarm m_part;
    public ParticleSwarm BackTestPartReport
    {
        get
        {
            return m_part;
        }
    }
```

I declare this

```
    public int Dim; //this part 
    public int NumParticles;

    public  double fit;
```

to add value .

```
    public SOSManager(CandleCollection collection)
    {
        CandleList = collection;            
        Calculate();

        m_backTesting = new BackTesting(this);
        fit = m_backTesting.fitness;

        //this part
        m_part = new ParticleSwarm(fit, Dim, NumParticles);
        m_part.Calculate(Dim,NumParticles);
        //

    }
```

Now,I can't get value from windows from into this class . What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the properties when it's too late, pass them into a constructor with more parameters:

```
public SOSManager(CandleCollection collection, int Dim, int NumParticles)
{
    // If you still need to store them as properties:
    this.Dim = Dim;
    this.NumParticles = NumParticles;
```

Then call it like this:

```
SOSManager p = new SOSManager(collection, Dim, NumParticles);
```